# how can i take part of string with C# 4.0 Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, c#-4.0

```
<a href="http://www.try.com"><strong>Try link word</strong></a>
```

Hello. how can i take this string part of

**http://www.try.com** and **Try link word**

with c# 4.0 regex ?

i try this but didn't work;

```
var expression = @"<a href=""(.*?)""><strong>(.*?)</strong>";
                        Match m = Regex.Match(text, expression);
                        while (m.Success)
                        {
                            Response.Write("Match: " + m.Groups[0] + " <br> Area code: " + m.Groups[1] +"<br><hr><br>");
                            m = m.NextMatch();
                        }
```

Comment: Didn't work how?  What did you get?

Comment: it's print =  <a href="http://www.try.com"><strong>Try link word</strong> <br> Area code: http://www.try.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and got this:

`Match: <a href="http://www.try.com"><strong>Try link word</strong> <br> Area code: http://www.try.com<br><hr><br>`

(psst, next time you have some code that "doesn't work", put what you did get in your question, as well as what you expected).

Changing:

`Response.Write("Match: " + m.Groups[0] + " <br> Area code: " + m.Groups[1] +"<br><hr><br>");`

to

`Response.Write("Match: " + m.Groups[1] + " <br> Area code: " + m.Groups[2] +"<br><hr><br>");`

got me this:

`Match: http://www.try.com <br> Area code: Try link word<br><hr><br>`

IS that what you wanted?